# Overloaded implementation of standard library functions

Tags: clojure

I'm currently learning Clojure and was looking at the implementation of `partial`. It implements a lot of cases concretely (and other functions do too) but `apply` also works with empty lists, so why is the implementation of `partial` so large? Why is it not:

```
(defn partial [f & args]
  (fn [& inner_args] 
    (apply f (concat args inner_args))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was done for performance:

- [Ticket](https://clojure.atlassian.net/browse/CLJ-1430)

  > This patch improves performance of partial by only using apply when needed. The code structure follows that of juxt.
- [Patch](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/commit/9c9bb2f7fda3daa86dea3dcf4de7d6b564cf147f)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK these are for performance reasons, for the most common use cases, 0-,1-,2-,3- artity it's a function call, else it does a (bit) more costly apply.

source for completeness (clj 1.10.1):

```
user=> (source partial)
(defn partial
  "Takes a function f and fewer than the normal arguments to f, and
  returns a fn that takes a variable number of additional args. When
  called, the returned function calls f with args + additional args."
  {:added "1.0"
   :static true}
  ([f] f)
  ([f arg1]
   (fn
     ([] (f arg1))
     ([x] (f arg1 x))
     ([x y] (f arg1 x y))
     ([x y z] (f arg1 x y z))
     ([x y z & args] (apply f arg1 x y z args))))
  ([f arg1 arg2]
   (fn
     ([] (f arg1 arg2))
     ([x] (f arg1 arg2 x))
     ([x y] (f arg1 arg2 x y))
     ([x y z] (f arg1 arg2 x y z))
     ([x y z & args] (apply f arg1 arg2 x y z args))))
  ([f arg1 arg2 arg3]
   (fn
     ([] (f arg1 arg2 arg3))
     ([x] (f arg1 arg2 arg3 x))
     ([x y] (f arg1 arg2 arg3 x y))
     ([x y z] (f arg1 arg2 arg3 x y z))
     ([x y z & args] (apply f arg1 arg2 arg3 x y z args))))
  ([f arg1 arg2 arg3 & more]
   (fn [& args] (apply f arg1 arg2 arg3 (concat more args)))))
```